# Occurrences in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays (this could be more arrays) and need to find the value that appears the most:

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
 string(6) "PD0001"
 [1]=>
 string(6) "PD0002"
}

array(2) {
 [0]=>
 string(6) "PD0001"
 [1]=>
 string(6) "PD0003"
}
```

So I'm trying to find PD0001, any suggestions?

Comment: appears in most arrays or appears the most times in all arrays combined?

Comment: Check out [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) :-)

Comment: Use `array_merge` and `array_count_values`.

Comment: I merged the arrays into $compare then I use $result = array_count_values($compare) it's then indexed by key, with PD0001 being at the top which is correct how do I get $result[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that can do that for you:

```
// First merge the arrays together
$array = array_merge($array1, $array2);

// Get the array counts like this:
$counts = array_count_values($array);

// Sort the array so the first one has the highest count
arsort($counts);

// Get the first key:
reset($counts);
$maxElement = key($counts);
```